# Can't render based on this.state in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Any idea why `{this.state.showTabBar === true ? this._renderTabBar : null}` fails in `SampleApp` component? Works fine if render just `<TabBarExample />`.

My goal is to use `this.state.showTabBar` to decide when to show TabBarIOS.

Here's a React Native Playground link:
https://rnplay.org/apps/5pQC9A

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TabBarIOS,
  TouchableHighlight,
} = React;


var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      showTabBar: true // I will eventually use this to decide 
                                        // if TabBarIOS will be visible.
    };
  },

  _renderTabBar: function() {
    return (
        <TabBarExample />
    );
  },

  render: function() {    
    return (         
      // This line fails.
      {this.state.showTabBar === true ? this._renderTabBar : null}

        // <TabBarExample /> // This will work if uncomment.
    );
  }
});


var TabBarExample = React.createClass({
  statics: {
    title: '<TabBarIOS>',
    description: 'Tab-based navigation.',
  },

  displayName: 'TabBarExample',

  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      selectedTab: 'blueTab',
      notifCount: 0,
      presses: 0,
    };
  },

  _renderContent: function(color: string, pageText: string, num?: number) {
    return (
      <View style={[styles.tabContent, {backgroundColor: color}]}>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>{pageText}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>{num} re-renders of the {pageText}</Text>
      </View>
    );
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <TabBarIOS
        tintColor="white"
        barTintColor="darkslateblue"
          translucent={true}>

        <TabBarIOS.Item
          title="Blue Tab"
          systemIcon="search"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'blueTab'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'blueTab',
            });
          }}>
          <MyViewOne />
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

        <TabBarIOS.Item
          title="Red Tab"
          systemIcon="history"
          badge={this.state.notifCount > 0 ? this.state.notifCount : undefined}
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'redTab'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'redTab',
              notifCount: this.state.notifCount + 1,
            });
          }}>
          {this._renderContent('#783E33', 'Red Tab', this.state.notifCount)}
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

        <TabBarIOS.Item
          systemIcon="contacts"
          title="More Green"
          selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'greenTab'}
          onPress={() => {
            this.setState({
              selectedTab: 'greenTab',
              presses: this.state.presses + 1
            });
          }}>
          {this._renderContent('#21551C', 'Green Tab', this.state.presses)}
        </TabBarIOS.Item>

      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
});


var MyViewOne = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (            
      <View style={[styles.tabContent, {backgroundColor: 'orange'}]}>
        <Text style={styles.tabText}>I like Iron Maiden</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
});


var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  tabContent: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
  tabText: {
    color: 'white',
    margin: 50,
  },  
  button: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',
    margin: 10,
  }  
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: What exactly does "fail" mean here? Do you get an error? Or not the result you expect? Please be more precise.

Comment: I can't open your playground link, but it looks like you are not actually calling the _renderTabBar method. You need to call it like this._renderTabBar()

Comment: Thanks, I was up way too late, and missed that. The error msg in React Native wasn't helping me, it was just showing syntax error in the column around "this.state.showTabBar", which threw me for a loop.

Comment: @GorkemYurtseven I have same issue at my day job, www.rnplay.org site is blocked by our firewall. Regarding calling func properly with (), still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Like Gortem said, you are not calling the function. React will not do it for you.

Also, instead of a ternary, your could do:

```
{this.state.showTabBar && this._renderTabBar()}
```

Or directly:

```
{this.state.showTabBar && (<TabBarExample />)}
```

Comment: Your && example is such bad coding style IMHO.

Comment: @GiantElk Whoah... Care to elaborate? If you're thinking that a ternary which is only used for one condition is "good", I guess my example is "bad" yes.

Comment: It's just too hard to read, in your code, it looks like: if this.state.showTabBar === true then you get {true && (<TabBarExample />)}, which translates to {true && true} which is {true}. At least that's how it looks to me. With explicit if then else or ternary operator it's obvious, no thinking required.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make showTabBar one of your state:

```
getInitialState: function(){
  return{
    showTabBar: {false}
  };
}
```

and use

```
this.setState({showTabBar:{true}});
```

to update

Comment: Yes, correct, but 1st I need to get basic render working.

Answer (score 1):

You should have your logic outside of the return statement like this:

```
render: function() {
  if (this.state.showTabBar) {
    return (this._renderTabBar());
  } else {
    return (<View />);
  }
}
```

It's also good to note that you will always need to return a component, even if it is a blank View.

Here is the working example: https://rnplay.org/apps/-TjJ7w

Comment: No, it doesn't matter where the logic resides, in a separate function object, or inline as you show. I was missing the () after this._renderTabBar. The result of coding while trying to stay away late night.

Comment: This is really messing with me, any idea why this doesn't work. Similar code works fine in ReactJS https://rnplay.org/apps/8LmYhQ

Comment: How do I write this with only 1 return statement in render? It's cleaner code IMO to have only 1 return per function/method.

Comment: Thanks. That's first time I've seen a var used in a render with < /> tags. I always put it inside {} on ReactJS web app.